# jQuery: Is it possible to stop a click or form submit and resume after firing a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, callback

I'm trying to write a simple script that effectively fades out the page content, then blends/fades in a new layer and then finally after those two fade animation have completed I need to make sure that the original trigger is activated.

So for example I have a `input type=submit` button that submits a form and saves some stuff to the database then returns you to the next step in the process, there is also a simple `<a>` tag that acts as the 'go back' button.

Here is my code:

```
$.fn.pageFade = function( direction , speed , callback ) {
    // make sure the callback is actually a function
    var callback = ( typeof callback == 'function' ? callback : null );
    // closure for the other params
    var direction = ( direction ? direction : 'out' ),
        speed     = ( speed ? speed : 400 );
    // new elements to be added to dom and manipulated
    var content =   $('#main'),
        shade   =   $("<div />", {
                        'id' : 'shade',
                        'css': {
                            'position':'absolute',
                            'top':0,
                            'left':0,
                            'width':'100%',
                            'height':'100%',
                            'background-color':'#fff',
                            'z-index':'-1'
                        }
                    });

    // do stuff
    if ( direction == 'out' ) { 

        // fade out of content then next page
        $(shade)
            .appendTo('body').hide();
        content.fadeOut( speed );
        $(shade).fadeIn( speed*4 , callback );

    } else {

        // on next page fade in the content (would be fired on load)
        content.hide();
        $(shade)
            .appendTo('body');
        $(shade).fadeOut( speed*4 );
        content.fadeIn( speed , callback );

    }

};

// attach to the triggers (go back & next buttons)
$("[name='submitNext'],.go-back").click(function(e) {
    // stop the default click so that the animation can fire instead of changing the page
    e.preventDefault();
    // start the fade out action, in the callback fire the original click
    $(this).pageFade('out', 400, function() {
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

The above (needless to say really) breaks because of recursion on the click event.

What I need to know is how to effectively "resume" the original even I stopped until after my animations have fired.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to resume, try defining what you want to have happen after your fade.

So your bottom code would be more like maybe:

```
// attach to the triggers (go back & next buttons)
$("[name='submitNext'],.go-back").click(function(e) {
    // stop the default click so that the animation can fire instead of changing the page
    e.preventDefault();
    // start the fade out action, in the callback fire the original click
    $(this).pageFade('out', 400, function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();//assuming this is what you want done after the fade.
    });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, this works in most cases though I have encountered some odd cases where because I stop the click on the submit button it's value is not being posted by the `form.submit()` that I fire after the animation. It would also be nice to just have a generic `resume` type action so that it would simply use the prevented event but this time fire it without prevention… but i guess i'm just dreaming of these possibilities. Thanks for this though.

Comment: @jannis I assume your thinking that preventDefault is stoping the action of your submit button, which this event handler is tied to the submit button, it is.  But the only thing a submit button is doing is the samething that a call to `$("form").submitO does.  To "resume" any event, just reproduce what the default handler would do.

Comment: Thanks, yes I realise that however ideally i wouldn't need to differentiate between clicking a link `<a>` or an `<input type='submit' />` button. Currently on click i need to trigger different callbacks on whether you're clicking an `a` or `input` as one would do the `window.location = el.attr('href')` whereas the `input` would need to run `$form.submit()`. I'd be nice to essentially auto detect the event and 'resume' it later in the same call without checking what this call should be.

Comment: @jannis You are correct, writing a global click event that doesn't have to explicitly check what was going to happen isn't supported.  There is a LOT of information in the event object that gets passed with events, you may want to look into that and see if there's other useful things for doing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your "trigger" click is calling the same function again.

you could call "submit" on the form element. `$("#myform").submit();`